# Server Side Looping

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I’ve solved this problem but looking for a better way to do it on the mongodb server rather that client.

I have one collection of Orders with a placement datetime (iso date) and a product.

```js
{ _id:1, datetime:“T1”, product:”Apple”} 
{ _id:2, datetime:“T2”, product:”Orange”} 
{ _id:3, datetime:“T3”, product:”Pear”}
{ _id:4, datetime:“T4”, product:”Pear”} 
{ _id:5, datetime:“T5”, product:”Apple”}
```

Goal: For a given time (or set of times) show the last order for EACH product in the set of my products before that time. Products are finite and known.

eg. query for time T6 will return:

```js
{ _id:2, datetime:“T2”, product:”Orange”} 
{ _id:4, datetime:“T4”, product:”Pear”} 
{ _id:5, datetime:“T5”, product:”Apple”}
```

T4 will return:

```js
{ _id:1, datetime:“T1”, product:”Apple”} 
{ _id:2, datetime:“T2”, product:”Orange”} 
{ _id:4, datetime:“T4”, product:”Pear”}
```

i’ve implemented this by creating a composite index on orders [datetime:descending, product:ascending]
Then on the java client:

```js
    findLastOrdersForTimes(times) {
    for (time: times) { 
        for (product: products) {
                db.orders.findOne(product:product, datetime: { $lt: time}}
        }
    }
}
```

Now that is pretty fast since it hits the index and only fetching the data i need. However I need to query for many time points (100000+) which will be a lot of calls over the network. Also my orders table will be very large. So how can I do this on the server in one hit, i.e return a collection of time->array products? If it was oracle, id create a stored proc with a cursor that loops back in time and collects the results for every time point and breaks when it gets to the last product after the last time point. I’ve looked at the aggregation framework and mapreduce but can’t see how to achieve this kind of loop. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want the last order for each product, then t[he aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) comes in:

```js
db.times.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "product": { "$in": products },
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$product",
        "datetime": { "$max": "$datetime" }
    }}
])
```

Example with an array of `products`:

```js
var products = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'];

{ "_id" : "Pear", "datetime" : "T4" }
{ "_id" : "Orange", "datetime" : "T2" }
{ "_id" : "Apple", "datetime" : "T5" }
```

Or if the `_id` from the original document is important to you, use the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) with [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) instead:

```js
db.times.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "product": { "$in": products },
    }},
    { "$sort": { "datetime": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$product",
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" },
        "datetime": { "$last": "$datetime" }
    }}
])
```

And that is what you most likely really want to do in either of those last cases. But the index you really want there is on "product":

```js
db.times.ensureIndex({ "product": 1 })
```

So even if you need to iterate that with an additional **`$match`** condition for **`$lt`** a certain timepoint, then that is better or otherwise you can modify the "grouping" to include the "datetime" as well as keeping a set in the **`$match`**.

It seems better at any rate, so perhaps this helps at least to modify your thinking.

---

If I'm reading out your notes correctly you seem to simply be looking for turning this on it's head and finding the last product for each point in time. So the statement is not much different:

```js
db.times.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "datetime": { "$in": ["T4","T5"] },
    }},
    { "$sort": { "product": 1, "datetime": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$datetime",
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" },
        "product": { "$last": "$product" }
    }}
])
```

That is in theory it is like that based on how you present the question. I have the feeling though that you are abstracting this though and "datetime" is possibly actual timestamps as date object types.

So you might not be aware of the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) you can apply, for example to get the boundary of each hour:

```js
db.times.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$datetime" },
            "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$datetime" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$datetime" }
        },
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" },
        "datetime": { "$last": "$datetime" },
        "product": { "$last": "$product" }
    }}
])
```

Or even using date math instead of the operators if a epoch based timestamp

```js
db.times.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [ 
                { "$subtract": [ "$datetime", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { "$mod": [ 
                    { "$subtract": [ "$datetime", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    1000*60*60 
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "id": { "$last": "$_id" },
        "datetime": { "$last": "$datetime" },
        "product": { "$last": "$product" }
    }}
])
```

Of course you can add a range query for dates in the **`$match`** with **`$gt`** and **`$lt`** operators to keep the data within the range you are particularly looking at.

Your overall solution is probably a combination of ideas, but as I said, your question seem to be about matching the last entries on certain time boundaries, so the last examples possibly in combination with filtering certain products is what you need rather than looping .`findOne()` requests.

Comment: Thanks Neil. But that's not what I want. That would work for one point in time, by adding a datetime < time to the match part. However I want the above output for many points of time. I.e. the input to the query would be an array of time points, and for each point I want the last set of orders for each product before that time. So in my example above, i want to do orders.find(times: ["T4","T6"]) and get back a collection keyed on times. {t4: [
{ _id:1...},
{ _id:2...},
{ _id:4...}
]
{t6:} [
{ _id:2...}, 
{ _id:4...},
{ _id:5...}
]

Comment: edited my original question to make it more clear. sry about that

Comment: @user3671663 Added some more information that seems like what you need as you seem to be looking for the last items at certain time intervals.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I think that's gone off on the wrong track but the stuff on dates is interesting. I need the last set of all products before a time. Which is  what your first answer gave. However I want to be able to get that same output for multiple times points. Still can't see how I can do that without multiple calls from the client. Although I have discovered the eval() command so possibly could use that with server side javascript to call the aggregate function for each time point in the request.